# "ModuleNotFoundError" when i run exe file

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, modulenotfounderror, pyperclip

I am trying to make an `exe` file out of my python script but whenever I try to run my `exe` file, it gives a

> Traceback error that pyperclip module not found.

I even tried to hidden import it using `--hidden-import` but still the same issue.
Can you please help me out?
Attached is the screenshot of the error whenever I run the `exe` file.
[image: Screenshot of the Error]

Comment: What are you using to create the exe file?

Comment: I used both pyinstaller and auto-py-to-exe but the issue remains

Comment: Have you installed `pynput`? Maybe you forgot to install it. Also, pyinstaller will output a log message like `analyzing hidden import 'pyperclip'` when building it. Also, `pyperclip` works in my environment.

Comment: @HassanShahzad Your issue is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68993691/16747588) try the solution given there.